# Django: generate python code from command line

Tags: python, django, django-commands

Is here a way to write a Django command to generate code automatically?

In my case: every time I create a new model I must create the following stuff too:

- Create Administration classes in `admin.py`
- Create service functions related to this model.
- Create a factory using FactoryBoy.
- Create test classes.

It would be nice if there was a command that generates this stuff automatically. Not everything, of course, but just the basic, the definition.

Is there something like this today in Django? Or is there a way I can write Django commands to generate code?

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally used it yet but you could try to use the third-party package 
Django baker [Django Baker](https://github.com/krisfields/django-baker) that offers that functionality

> Django Baker wants to help you get your projects up and running
>   quickly. Given one or more app names, s/he will automatically generate
>   views, forms, urls, admin, and templates for all of the models in the
>   models.py file. All files are pep-8 compliant (with exception to the
>   maximum line length rule, which I don't agree with).
>
> Once you add a single urlpattern to your project's URLconf, you'll
>   have a working list view, detail view, create view, update view, and
>   delete view for each model in your app.
>
> Optionally you may specify which models in an app to bake if you'd
>   rather not generate files for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try  django commands and [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) templates.

With the  execution of custom defined command, set of file templates can be updated with appropriate content and copied to respective folders as per need.